# Robotium solo waitForCondition

Tags: android, robotium

I'm using the robotium. Today I ran into with little problem. After click on button application crosses to the next activity. I need wait for appearance some button.

```
View am = solo.getView(R.id.btn_login);

solo.waitForCondition(am.isShown(), 5000);
```

This code doesn't work.

It also doesn't work if **am** is identified like

```
Button am = solo.getButton(R.id.btn_login);
```

Help me please figure it out!

Comment: Could you please send us your class please? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You've to implement the [`Condition`](http://robotium.googlecode.com/svn/doc/com/jayway/android/robotium/solo/Condition.html) interface:

```
solo.waitForCondition(new Condition() {
   @Override
   public boolean isSatisfied() {
       return am.isShown();
   }
}, 5000);
```

In `isSatisfied()` you are quite free to test whatever you need :)

Answer (score 0):

isShown() in Android is very often misunderstood. It returns true, when view and all of its ancestors are visible.

I think you could just try:

```
solo.waitForView(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Robotium, there are different waitForCondition. Such as:

```
solo.waitForView() //if a certain view is shown after the load screen is done.
solo.waitForDialogToClose() //waits for the dialog to close
solo.waitForActivity() // if there is a activity change
solo.waitForText() //if a certain text appears after the loading is done
```

In your case, since you know the id of the waited item, you can try:

```
solo.waitForView(R.id.btn_login, 5000);
```